# C++ program printing random values

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I was trying OOP with C++. I declared a class `testOOP` and created some private members in it. I added the value in the encapsulated array with `add(int x)` function. But when I tried to print it through `printArray` method it is outputting incorrect result.

Below is what I tried. Can somebody explain me why I am getting result different than `20 10 30 40`?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class testOOP
{
    private:
        int *a;
        int size;
        int last;

    public:
        testOOP();
        void add(int);
        void printArray();
};

testOOP::testOOP(void){

    size = 15;
    last = -1;
    int data[size];
    a = data;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        *(a+i)=0;
        //cout<<*(a+i);
        //cout<<"\n";
    }
}


void testOOP::printArray(){
    for(int i=0;i<=last;i++){
        cout<<*(a+i)<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

void testOOP::add(int x){
    if(last+1 != size){
        last = last+1;
        *(a+last)=x;
    }
}

int main( )
{
    testOOP A;
    A.add(20);
    A.add(10);
    A.add(30);
    A.add(40);
    A.printArray();
    return 0;
}
```

And if possible how I can fix this issue?

Comment: `data` is local to your constructor, it is destroyed as soon as the constructor ends. `a` is then a dangling pointer, and you're not allowed to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code in the constructor:

```
int data[size];
a = data;
```

`data` is a local array which will be destroyed when go out of the constructor. Then `a` will be dangled, dereference on it is UB. You could

1.`new[]` the array in the constructor (and `delete[]` it in the destructor). Such as:

```
testOOP::testOOP(void){

    size = 15;
    last = -1;
    a = new int[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        *(a+i)=0;
        //cout<<*(a+i);
        //cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

2.use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 0):

The constructor

```
testOOP::testOOP(void){

    size = 15;
    last = -1;
    int data[size];
    a = data;
   //...
```

is invalid. Frist of all C++ does not support variable length arrays. So this declaration of an array

```
    size = 15;
    int data[size];
```

is invalid.

Pointer a points to the first element of the local array `data` that will be destroyed after exiting the constructor. So it will have an invalid value and the program will have undefined behaviour.

You could initially make the array data member of the class instead of the pointer.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

class testOOP
{
private:
    const static size_t max_size = 15;
    int a[max_size];
    size_t last;

public:
    testOOP() : a{}, last( 0 ) {}
    void add( int x )
    {
        if ( last != max_size ) *( a + last++ ) = x;
    }        
    void printArray( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < last; i++ ) os << *( a + i ) << ' ';
        os << std::endl;
    }        
};

int main()
{
    testOOP A;
    A.add(20);
    A.add(10);
    A.add(30);
    A.add(40);

    A.printArray();
}
```

The program output is

```
20 10 30 40
```

If your compiler does not support such an initialization of arrays in the ctor initializer list

```
testOOP() : a{}, last( 0 ) {}
            ^^^
```

then you can just write

```
testOOP() : last( 0 ) 
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < max_size; i++ ) *( a + i ) = 0;
}
```

Comment: so how should i deal with this situation. could you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
int data[size];
a = data;
```

are incorrect. You create an array on stack and assign it to a class member variable. This stack-allocated memory is freed when the code reaches the end of `testOOP::testOOP`.

You should use `new` in you constructor and `delete[]` in the destructor or use `std::vector` that handles memory automatically.

```
testOOP::testOOP() : size(15), last (-1), a (new int [size]) {
... // fill in the array
}

// also update your class declaration so that 'a' is declared after 'size',
// otherwise 'a(new int[size])' will use uninitialized size

//add the destuctor:
testOOP::~testOOP() { delete [] a; }
```